# Intersect array of hashes with array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes, this is not an active record model.  This array is of objects of type `Person` with properties of `id`, `name`, `age`.  I have a second array of strings, `["john", "james", "bill"]`.

I am attempting to remove all objects in the array of hashes except for the ones who have names in the second array, essentially performing an intersect, but I'm having quite a few problems.  Any suggestions?  I'm not sure if my syntax is just off or if I'm thinking about this the wrong way.  Obviously I can just iterate through but this seems like its probably not the best way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-select

```
arr1 = [{:id => 1, :name => "John"}, {:id => 2, :name => "Doe"}];
arr2 = ["Doe"];

intersect = arr1.select {|o| arr2.include? o[:name]} # you can also use select!
p intersect # outputs [{:name=>"Doe", :id=>2}]
```

Comment: I'd make a set out of `arr2`, which removes the O(n) lookup cost.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but if arr1 :name is an array this works nicely:

```
arr1 = [{:id => 1, :name => ["John", "Doe"]}, {:id => 2, :name => ["Doe"]}];
arr2 = ["Doe"]

> intersect = arr1.reject{|o| (arr2 & o[:name]).empty?}
=> [{:id=>1, :name=>["John", "Doe"]}, {:id=>2, :name=>["Doe"]}] #output

> arr2 = ["John"]
> intersect = arr1.reject{|o| (arr2 & o[:name]).empty?}
=> [{:id=>1, :name=>["John", "Doe"]}] #output
```

or use select:

```
intersect = arr1.select{|o| !(arr2 & o[:name]).empty?}
```

To remove all objects in the array of hashes except for the ones who have names in the second array, you can do:

```
arr1.reject!{|o| (arr2 & o[:name]).empty?}
```