# Find intersection of arrays of hashes by hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, intersection

If I have an 2 arrays of hashes for example:

```
user1.id
=> 1
user2.id
=> 2

user1.connections = [{id:1234, name: "Darth Vader", belongs_to_id: 1}, {id:5678, name: "Cheese Stevens", belongs_to_id: 1}]

user2.connections = [{id:5678, name: "Cheese Stevens", belongs_to_id: 2}, {id: 9999, "Blanch Albertson", belongs_to_id: 2}]
```

Then how in Ruby can I find the intersection of these two arrays by the hashes id value?

So that for the above example

```
intersection = <insert Ruby code here>
=> [{id: 5678, name: "Cheese Stevens"}]
```

I can't just use `intersection = user1.connections & user2.connections` because the belongs_to_id is different.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersect array of hashes with array of ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828277/intersect-array-of-hashes-with-array-of-ids)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple as that:

```
user1.connections & user2.connections
```

if you want only by the id key (other attributes are different)

```
intersection = user1.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]} & user2.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]}
user1.connections.select {|h| intersection.include? h[:id] }
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, let me update then, say there is also a field called belongs_to_id which differs since one belongs to user1 and one belongs to user2. This is why I need to find the intersection based on the value of the id value in the hash. I will update to clarify.

Comment: if you want only by the id key (other attributes are different)

`intersection = user1.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]} & user1.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]}
    user1.connections.select {|h| intersection .include? h[:id] }`

Comment: Should it be intersection = user1.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]} & user2.connections.map{|oh| oh[:id]} instead?